# Когда словосочетание "кем является" выделяется запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Она никогда не забудет тот миг, когда обнаружила **кем** является Эдик.*
Вопрос: надо ли перед местоимением *кем* ставить запятую и по какому правилу?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы, исчерпывающе  и понятно.

Comment: _Я тут первый раз, поясните, пожалуйста, почему была нужна правка..._  1. Заголовок — вопросительное предложение (я поставила знак вопроса). 2. Разделила собственно предложение (и выделила его _курсивом_) от формулировки вопроса. ТАК лучше для восприятия. 3. Исправила "**после** кем" на "**перед** кем" — что соответствует заданному вопросу.

Comment: Спасибо, что не прошли мимо, а сделали так, что ответ я получила. Я уже немножко почитала правила и поняла - ответа могло бы не быть, если бы вопрос повис в категории "требующий правки".

Answer (score 2):

(1)Она никогда не забудет **тот миг (какой?),** (2) **когда** обнаружила (что?), (3) **кем** является Эдик.

Это сложное предложение с последовательным подчинением, состоит из трех предложений.

Предложение 1: ***тот*** – указательное слово, ***миг*** – опорное существительное.

Предложение 2: придаточное определительное, ***когда*** – союзное слово,

Предложение 3: придаточное изъяснительное (дополнительное), ***кем*** – союзное слово.

Answer (score 0):

Это союзное слово, соединяющее части предложения. .Поэтому запятая ставится.

Comment: _Поэтому запятая ставится._ — А Вы точно вопрос прочитали внимательно?

Comment: Уважаемый grizzly, а каково ваше мнение в этом случае?

Comment: @ivanna Запятая нужна **перед** местоимением *кем*. Я не сомневаюсь, что и **Третий глаз** говорил о том же, но был невнимателен, как и Вы :)

Comment: Ой, не видела Вашу полемику перед правкой. Вернуть?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Нет, что Вы. Спасибо за правку — я должен был сам, конечно, раз заметил первым.

Comment: Чтобы прояснить для себя ситуацию. Предложение является сложноподчиненным бессоюзным? Первая основа - она никогда не забудет тот миг, когда обнаружила, вторая - кем является Эдик. И запятая перед местоимением "кем" разделяет две эти части. Правильно?

Comment: Я тут первый раз, поясните, пожалуйста, почему была нужна правка и что в правилах почитать, чтобы далее все было корректно.

Comment: Читайте ответ @Jasmin - Там все ясно изложено по поводу основ.